# Table not visible and buttons not working when added through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm playing with blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload Demo.
I've been studying it for the past days and I think I have a pretty good understanding of how it works. However, I have little experience with web development and there's one problem that's intriguing me.

In the Basic-UI-Plus part of the demo, the files queued for uploading (the ones selected via the Add button) are displayed using JavaScript-Templates

```
 <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody class="files"></tbody>
 </table>
```

The template will be rendered and its output will be placed in the block that has the "files" class. In this example it's the "tbody" block.

However, if I try to output the table tags from the template as well:

```
<div class="files">
     <!-- Template's output comes here: it will contain <table></table> -->
</div>
```

According to FireBug's DOM viewer everything will be rendered as expected, but the table will not be visible. After testing with different layouts I've realised that if I remove the "fade" class from the "tr" generated with the template then the table will be visible, but the demo will not work as expected. Neither of the start buttons will now work.

Here are the two jsfiddles:

[The working one](http://jsfiddle.net/0hhvt522/) will display the table of queued files correctly. When pressing any of the two 'Start' blue buttons it will try to upload and say that the server is not found as expected.

[The strange one](http://jsfiddle.net/3vstakxr/) will not display any table whatsoever, although it is shown correctly in firebug. After removing the "fade" class or adding the "in" class as suggested below, everything will be shown, but none of the start buttons will work.

Can anyone explain me what is actually going on? Thanks!

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine

Comment: Are you suggesting it's template related? I doubt it, because the output of the template is correct. It's the buttons that are not working

Answer (score 0):

When having the `fade` class, an element is totally opaque, that's the reason why you're not seeing it. To make it visible again you have to add the `in` class to it as well. Visually it works just fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/xkych55n/1/ and note the slight difference at line 163 in HTML code.

Comment: Indeed, it works visually, but the start buttons aren't working as expected

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the script thinks that the files are the direct children of the "files" container.

So if you have `<table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files">` it finds the children of `<tbody>` which are the `<tr>`s containing the files.

If you change that to `<div class="files"><tableclass="table"><tbody>` it will think that the `<table>` element is a file rather than the `<tr>`s.

I would just change the HTML to `<div class="files"><table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table></div>` and leave the rest the same. No point in changing the javascript.

---

An alternative is to get rid of the table completely, just make sure that the files are direct children of the container... so for example:

Container:

```
<div class="files"></div>
```

Template:

```
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <div class="template-upload fade">
        <div>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% } %}
</script>
```

You would then, of course, have to fix the styling. **[Here a working jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3vstakxr/2/)**

Note: You have errors on lines 191 and 236. `</table></tbody>` should be `</tbody></table>`.